# How to run useEffect in React after POST request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-hooks, fetch-api

Tasks doesn't update (not unless I refresh the page) after submitting/creating a new task. Seems like the useEffect is not running during handleSubmitForm.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const Tasks = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getTasks();
  }, []);

  const getTasks = async () => {
    const response = await ('/tasks/');
    const data = await response.json()
    setTasks(data);
  };

  const [task, setTask] = useState("");

  const handleSubmitForm = (e) => {
    fetch("/tasks/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: task, completed: false }),
    })
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      <div>
        <input
          onInput={(e) => {
            setTask(e.target.value);
          }}
          value={task}
        />
        <button onClick={handleSubmitForm}>Add</button>
      </div>
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        return <li key={task.id}>{task.title}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Tasks;
```

I'm fairly new with react and it's 2 days now I still can't figure it out.

Comment: `const response = await ('/tasks/');`: what's happening here? Did you mean `const response = await fetch('/tasks/');`?

Comment: @Andy Sorry just a little typo when I was editing here in stackoverflow. Yes, I meant `const response = await fetch('/tasks/');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After successfully submitting a new task, you should add it to your tasks array. After that React will automatically re-render your tasks for you (since your tasks state was updated).

```
const handleSubmitForm = (e) => {
    fetch("/tasks/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: task, completed: false }),
    }).then(() => {
      setTasks([...tasks, { title: task, completed: false }]);
    })

  };
```

Comment: It worked! Omg thanks!!!!! Seems a little easy but I can't figure it out. Thank you! I also tried running getTasks function, `.then(() => getTasks());` it also worked. Which one is better to use?

Comment: So it depends on the use case. Are tasks user bound? or are they available to more users? Are we thinking on scaling the app?
My opinion if it is a simple case of a "todo app" where we are just planning on having 1 user messing around, the setState works fine. If we are planning on a more complicated structure either re-fetch with getTasks() or consider using websockets for real time updates to the tasks in the backend.
Also if we are thinking of tasks having hundreds of objects, re-fetching everything might not be worth it, wasted bandwidth and wasted process power on the backend/frontend.

Comment: @codewithbersh Small aside: since you're using `await` for the other `fetch` it might make sense to refactor this answer to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is call  getTasks() in the .then of your fetch function

```
const handleSubmitForm = (e) => {
    fetch("/tasks/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: task, completed: false }),
    }).then(() => {
       getTasks();
    })

  };
```